# How can I use a cycles material animated procedural texture to control hair particles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, particles

As the question says, I want to distribute hair particles using animated procedural textures of a cycles material. The effect I want to achieve is something like that:
[image]
I can make a material to previsualize the areas the particles will cover, but I can't use the texture in the material node editor in the particles stack.
I try to use the texture node editor, but when movin the texture the particles just apear and disapear not making any grow o size variation.

Any help will be welcome! Thank You!!

PS: Sorry about any spalling error, not natural english user :)

EDIT:
Thanks for the comment Duarte Farrajota Ramos.

As I say in the comment, I'm trying with dynamic paint now. But the particles aren't taking the vertex group as a distributor at all.
[image: print screen]
I can't find the error yet, I did it once with that method but I was hopeing to get more control using textures, avoiding the Dinamyc Paint need to use an object to paint and another to erase the paint.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, you can't use cycles textures outside rendering, nor can you use node textures for particles

Comment: I did'n know that. I'm trying with dynamic paint now. But the particles aren't taking the vertex group as a distributor at all.